# Is it safe to delete a void* byte by byte?

Tags: c++, allocation

Because i don't know verry much about memory allocation, I would like to know if it safe to delete a block of consecutive bytes (array) like this.

```
void Free(void* ptr, size_t cbSize)
{
    if (cbSize == 0) return;
    if (ptr == NULL) return;

    for(size_t i = cbSize; i > 0; i--)
    {
        char* p = &((char*)ptr)[i];
        delete p;
    }

    char* p = (char*) (ptr);
    delete p;
}
```

I have tried this method in the following circumstances and got no error.

```
int* a = new int[100];
Free(a, 100 * sizeof(int));

int* a = (int*) malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
Free(a, 100 * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: ***Is it safe to delete a void* byte by byte?*** No. You can only delete the whole thing or nothing. Also you can't use delete with malloc().

Comment: I know `free()` from `stdlib` can only be used when allocating with `malloc()` but when using `new`, `delete [] void*` is undefined. How can i make my function work in this case ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You always delete what you allocate; exactly and *only* what you allocate. If you `new` a single thing, you `delete` a single thing. The fact that the "single thing" happens to take up more than one byte is irrelevant; you `delete` what you `new`.

> How can i make my function work in this case ?

You don't. You `new`ed an array of `int`s. So you must `delete` an array of `int`s. Types matter in C++.